# while im deleting zip folder getting An Error as The directory name is invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

i have a folder like

```
  String path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images");
```

This folder im converting into Zip

```
 string zipPath = path + ".zip";
            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(path, zipPath, CompressionLevel.Fastest, true);
```

Again I'm deleting this flder as

```
 System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\EMS BackUP\Mohd_Ems\EMSIMPORTANTSOURCECODE\EMS_SOURCE_CODE\EMS\EMS\Images.zip");
            dir.Attributes = dir.Attributes & ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
            dir.Delete(true);
```

at dir.Delete(true) i'm getting An Error as The directory name is invalid.

Comment: Images.zip is a file. Not a directory.

Comment: if i remove images.zip from my url im getting Error as The process cannot access the file 'HelpPage.css' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: What process is using `HelpPage.css`? That seems like the issue here. You can't delete a file that is currently in use. You can use [processxp to determine which process is tying that file up](https://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-find-out-which-windows-process-using-file.htm)

Comment: @JNevill this was deleted my enter folder

Comment: what can i do now

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you are trying to do. You are zipping a folder into `images.zip`. Then you are trying to delete that zip? Delete the original folder?

Comment: @JNevill yes I deleted Enter the folder even its not in Recycle Bin

Answer (score 0):

Please try with `System.IO.Directory.Delete(path,true)`
Recursively delete all files